# WinRT App with High resolution background images

Tags: image, background, windows-runtime, resolution

I'm working on a WinRT App that has multiple pages using the Basic Page template. Each page has 1366*768 resolution background images and when navigating from a page to another there's an undesired and annoying blinking effect. Is there any trick I could get rid of it? I've had some tries to look upon the images' properties but no luck so far. Can this be achieved?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I remove this by setting the image on the background of the main frame.

In you app.cs file add the following code:-

> ```
>     protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
>     {
>         Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
>         ImageBrush brush = new ImageBrush();
>         BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("..."));
>         brush.ImageSource = image;
>         rootFrame.Background = brush;
> ```

That prevents the flickering.

Comment: this is the simplest solution.. (Y) might need to set your rootGrid background as "Transparent" for all the pages

Answer (score 1):

Ross's answer is simple and close to what I thought of doing. I would probably use two Image controls though and alternate between them setting the pictures + run a dissolve transition animation once the new image loads.

I think the way things work with WinRT XAML is when you navigate to a new page that has images in the visual tree - it might delay opening the new page for a fraction of a second to wait for the images to load, but only for a short time. I think that is what happens because I saw new pages open with images loaded on my laptop, but it seems like it times out because on a Surface - it shows without the images first and they only pop in later.

If you wanted to give WinRT XAML Toolkit a shot - it has some other mechanisms that might help you. The AlternativeFrame used with AlternativePage is a swap-in for Frame/Page that has an almost the same API, but the Navigate methods are asynchronous, it allows you to wait for the next page to load its images (with ShouldWaitForImagesToLoad="True" set on the frame or page) or other content before opening it and has support for page transitions. It also has a Preload() method that allows you to preload the next page in memory before you call Navigate, so it is ready to show up when the user's action invokes the navigate call (assuming you don't have many options for where to navigate to from where you are).

Another tool you might use from there is ImageExtensions.FadeInOnLoaded property that makes your image fade in smoothly when they load instead of just popping up.

Comment: There is a contentTheme transition I can already apply without the use of any other elements... but this seems to use the black color for tranisition... I can't seem to figure how to use a different color.. like white for example...

Comment: I think what you are talking about is when the elements fade in and that could work. The black is the background color, so you would need to specify white for whatever is behind the content that you are fading in. AlternativeFrame allows you to do a dissolve transition where you don't suddenly hide the previous page, but rather fade in the new one on top of the old one.